# Javascript Uncaught TypeError issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-7, uncaught-exception

I am facing this strange errors related to jquery that are impacting my page functionality. Below is the error details that i see in console of browsers:

Chrome:-

```
     Uncaught TypeError: Object <site-config><site-name>Investment solutions for your every need</site-name><logo><src>/core/library/images/am_logo.jpg</src><alt>.........</module-group><module-group id="site"><modules></modules></module-group></module-groups></site-config> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'
(anonymous function)                              jquery.min.js : 19
```

IE7/8:-

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 12:36:02 UTC


Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
```

Since it shows error in line 19 of jquery.min.js, file which i am referring from google server then what should be wrong ??

Thanks !!

Comment: in FireFox: `Error: TypeError: siteConfig.getElementsByTagName is not a function`

Comment: The error is with your search.js. Also your XML is not XML, the browser sees it as "Content-Type text/plain" Your server is not setting the correct content type. Plus I do not see the XML Declaration.